# Extent report , Not displayed Properly format in the email body

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-extent-report

i am using extent Report for reporting of automation scripts ,i want to send automation report in the email body for this i am using email editable email notification  , `HTML report` ,in the editable email i am using the pre send script technique

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("target/surefire-reports/extent-Report/ExtentReport.html")
  msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");
```

, Mail is being sent successfully but in body of email report, is not properly presentable , means there is css issue  there is any one who can help me out for this [image: EMail Body]

Comment: When I was playing with DJango, I had to put whole CSS into the HTML file ;) Give it a try and let me know if it helped

Comment: but i had no css or html file in my scenario

Comment: Whats this then ? ~> ExtentReport.html ?

Comment: yes i had the extent.tml report

Comment: how i can put the css into the html file? can u help me ?

Comment: Easiest way is to put in a head the whole css file in <style> :)

Comment: can u explain how i can put css file in style , but i had only extent.html file , you can elaborate it?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp here ya go :) good luck